# How do I seed my MVC model with HttpPostedFileBase type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seeding, httppostedfilebase

I've searched high and low for this answer but can't find anything.... am I being daft?

```
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        context.Items.Add(new Item
        {
            URL = "my-url-field",
            Title = "My Title for this Item",
            Image = "some-image-file.jpg"  // this is httppostedfilebase  - how to seed this?
        });
    }
```

I imagine I'd have to instantiate an object of httppostedfilebase, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `HttpPostedFileBase` is the wrong property for your model.  You probably want instead to have the `Image` property as a `byte[]` - this is what will be stored in the database.  If you require the filename as well, you could just make that a string property on `Item`

Then, your seed method would look like

```
...
Image = File.ReadAllBytes("some-image-file.jpg"),
Filename = "some-image-file.jpg"
...
```

Comment: Thank you Stan.... I think I got the wrong end of the stick somewhere. I thought the httppostedfilebase would automagically give me file upload as the input in the editors. Would a byte[] property store the image file as binary in the DB?  I'm thinking that I should probably just be going for a string type filename property.

Comment: yes - byte[] would be for if you plan on storing the actual file data in the DB.  If you are uploading files, your action will need httppostedfilebase to get the file - however this shouldn't be part of your EF model - this should just be part of your ViewModel

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for clarifying all those bits.